# If $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x,y \in G$ then $G$ must be abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm a little stuck on an exercise from my intro to abstract algebra class. Here's my proof so far

Let $G$ be a group and suppose $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x,y \in G$.
Notice $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}$ and $yx=y^{-1}x^{-1}=(xy)^{-1}$.
So
$$(xy)(yx)=(xy)(xy)^{-1}=e=(yx)(yx)^{-1}=(yx)(xy)$$
so $(xy)(yx)=(yx)(xy)$ which is only possible if $G$ is Abelian.

I'm thinking it isn't enough to conclude by just seeing these products commute but I was having trouble getting to $xy=yx$. Thanks for any advice in advanced!

Comment: Try separating the $x,y $ terms on opposite sides.

Answer (score 12):

With $y=1$, the given condition imlpies $x=x^{-1}$ or $xx=1$ for all $x$. Especially, $$xy=1xy=yyxy=y1yxy=yxxyxy=yx(xy)(xy)=yx1=yx.$$

---

If you only have $(xy)(yx)=(yx)(xy)$, i.e., that certain elements *of specific form* commute, this might not imply that *arbitrary* elements commute. [As a contrived example of similar kind: If we have $(xx)(yy)=(yy)(xx)$ for all $x,y\in G$, $G$ need not be abelian; for example, $G$ coul dbe a dihedral group.] What you'd need would be to show that for arbitrary elements $u,v$ you could find $x,y$ such that $u=xy$ and $v=yx$; but this is not possible in general as it requires that $v=yuy^{-1}$, i.e., $u,v$ aare conjugate.

Comment: I think you should also mention whether h/is/er answer is true or not. (Or missing point)

Comment: Perhaps slightly more natural is to look at the commutator $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = (xy)^2 = 1$.

Comment: Otherwise this question is a duplicate as it is asked here many times.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I was looking through the questions that came up when I searched it and while writing it to post and I couldn't find it. Thanks everybody! In our class we use 'e' as the identity, so I'm assuming you are using 1 as the identity?

Comment: can someone tell me if what I did was wrong in my short answer, thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

A genial idea would be (applying successively $ab=(ba)^{-1}$ firstly for $a=x,b=y$ and second for $a=yx, b=1$):
$$ xy=(yx)^{-1}=\left(\left(yx\right)1\right)^{-1}=\left(\left(1\left(yx\right)\right)^{-1}\right)^{-1}=\left((yx)^{-1}\right)^{-1}=yx$$

Comment: There is nothing _wrong_ here, but I think Hagen's answer (and in particular Pedro's improvement suggestion) is more instructive -- especially pointing out _expliticly_ that the assumption implies $x=x^{-1}$ is worthwhile. You actually do have the argument for this in your middle three $=$s (applied to $yx$), but it's not set out as a relevant insight in itself.

Comment: @Henning Makholm just to be sure thanks you!

Comment: I don't really follow this argument. Why are we taking another inverse after the 3rd equals sign.

Comment: let's say $R: ab=(ba)^{-1}$, the first equality is $R$ for $a,b=x,y$ and the second equality is a simplification, the third equality is $R$ for $a,b=1,(yx)$ and the final equalities are just simplifactions.